# SQL Free Text And Like

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-indexing

If I use like '%fish%' the following is returned

AQUARIAN GOLDFISH FLAKES

but if I use Contains([Description],' "fish*" ' ) it isn't is there something I can do?

Basically I want to return anything that has the word fish in it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
 CONTAINS([Description], '"fish"')
```

or

```
 FREETEXT([Description], 'fish')
```

Does that give you anything?

SQL Server Fulltext indexing does not support searching for an expression with a leading wildcard, e.g. you cannot go a `CONTAINS([Description], '"*fish*"')` or something like that :-(

What you could also do is define your own synonym for fulltext search, e.g. define "goldfish" to be a synonym for "fish" - than you should be able to search for just "fish" and also find "goldfish".

```
SELECT (list of fields) FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS([Description], 'FORMSOF(THESAURUS, fish)')
```

Check out [Understanding Full-Text Indexing in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/) - there's a good section a bit down in the article on modifying the fulltext thesaurus.

Marc